# Is there a way to send prerecorded requests to a server?

Tags: networking

I was wondering if it is possible to record and replay outbound POST requests from a Windows PC, and replay them. For example, if I have a POST recorder, and I send a request from Skype to make a call, can I record that request and replay it without Skype running?

In short: I am looking for an app that can work as a POST recorder and can replay prerecorded requests.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is what you want. It is able to record, modify and replay network requests.
Target application must support HTTP proxy though.

But repeated requests to a monitored server might get you banned/blocked.

Comment: Not really what I was working since I need to monitor port 5223, not HTTP, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` (available in Windows via [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)) can send POST data with a request.  You must have previously captured it, or create it on the fly, you can use a web proxy such as [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) to snoop on an existing HTTP/HTTPS session and capture POST data of a request.

Note that accomplishing what you want will very unlikely be as simple as sending a simple request with specific POST data, and may involve multiple domains and multiple protocols (services may talk JSON, raw XML, another XML-based protocol, or another protocol entirely).  Each request may need to have a unique element, such as a request key, to work.  Typically applications expect you to have logged in, so you need to issue requests emulating that as well, and there are many ways to make it difficult to do automatically.

You are in for a lot of work.  Good luck.